# Chrome translator add DOM and breaks code

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-translator-toolkit

Chequear traducir correos-app se pifia

I have my app with a sidebar working ok, with this rendered code (the actual code is pure php and javascript, that's why I paste a screenshot of the chrome dev inspector):
[image]
and looks like this:
[image]

But when I use the Chrome Translator, it changes my code in DOM, it gets like:
[image]

And of course, it's rendered as:
[image]

Why happens that? any idea on how to avoid it? I need to use the translator. Thanks.